# Protractor Jasmine describe inside it block not working

Tags: selenium, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying new to jasmine and am trying to implement a sharing steps in jasmine.
am trying to share few of the steps between 2 scenarios. So am just try to execute a shared describe block inside a it block and it doesn't execute it. below is just a sample code.

```
describe('Main Method 1', (){
  it('Function 1', (){
      console.log('Function 1');
      describe('Function 1',(){
         it('Function 1.1',(){
         console.log('Function 1.1');
         })
         it('Function 1.2',(){
         console.log('Function 1.2');
         })
      });
  });
  it('Function 2', (){
      console.log('Function 2');
      describe('Function 2',(){
         it('Function 2.1',(){
         console.log('Function 2.1');
         })
         it('Function 2.2',(){
         console.log('Function 2.2');
         })
      });
  });
});
```

This Function 1 and Function 2 are a different scenario. I wanted to share the particular scenario with Main Method1.

Function 1 & Function 2 are getting printed and the Function 1.1 Function 1.2 and Function 2.1 and Function 2.2 is not printing.

Someone can share a idea on this will help me more.

Actual Implementation are more like

```
describe('Main Method', (){
   it('F1', () {
       Function1();
   });
   it('F2', () {
       Function2();
   });
});

Function1(){
  describe('Function 1',(){
     it('Function 1.1',(){
     console.log('Function 1.1');
     })
     it('Function 1.2',(){
     console.log('Function 1.2');
     })
  });
}
Function2(){
  describe('Function 2',(){
     it('Function 2.1',(){
     console.log('Function 2.1');
     })
     it('Function 2.2',(){
     console.log('Function 2.2');
     })
  });
}
```

Comment: I found the issue.. The issue is that the describe  or it statement inside an it statement won't work.. ie nested it blocks won't work in jasmine..

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap all similar tests into one `describe` and if you want to call something before them you use `beforeAll` and if after then `afterAll`. You can also do something between tests with `beforeEach()` function.

Each `it`  block should be responsible for performing one operation (such as "Open browser", "Click login button", etc.), so putting `describe` block inside `it` is not a good idea.

```
describe('Main Method 1', () {

    describe('Function 1', () {

     beforeAll(function() {
         console.log('Start of Function 1');
     });

     beforeEach(function() {
         console.log('Start of next test');
     });

     afterAll(function() {
         console.log('End of Function 1');
     });

     it('Function 1.1',(){
         OpenPage();
     });

     it('Function 1.2',(){
         console.log('Function 1.2');
     });
  });

    describe('Function 2', () {

     beforeAll(function() {
         console.log('Start of Function 2');
     });

     it('Function 2.1',(){
         OpenPage();
     });

     it('Function 2.2',(){
         console.log('Function 2.2');
     });
  });
});

function OpenPage() {
    // open page 
    browser.get('http://google.com/');
    // More code you don't want to repeat.
}
```

Comment: the describe  Function1 & Function 2 are the separate test case I just want to reuse that test case in the describe Main Method. (to avoid the duplication of the code).

Comment: You can create a function a call it. That's what they are for.

Comment: I just updated my question with the function call... it doesn't execute the it blocks inside the function..

Comment: Because you don't put `it` or `describe` block inside these functions. You only put functionality. I updated my answer.